# Read and delete from FIFO in C

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo

I am building a server that communicates through FIFO with it's clients.

So far I've managed to create a FIFO, run a new thread, once a message arrives in the FIFO and output the message from the thread.

The problem is that as soon as the client writes something in the pipe, the server just prints the message endlessly (I am reading from the pipe in a `while(1)`).

My question is: shouldn't the `read` operation also remove the message from the pipe, so it doesn't get read again? Isn't that the point of First In, First **Out**? Is that something I have to do manually?

Here's my code too, if that helps: http://pastebin.com/Ag7vgrav
What I do to write in the FIFO is just: `echo test > /home/ubuntu/work/my_fifo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the return code from `read(2)`.  If it returns -1, an error occurred, and you should stop reading immediately.  If it returns 0, that's EOF, meaning the writer closed its end of the FIFO and you should also stop writing and close your end of the FIFO.

In order to support multiple clients, you need to reopen the FIFO every time you accept a new client.

You also have some undefined behavior in the way you're managing the child thread.  There's no guarantee that the thread will start up before the end of the current iteration of the `while` loop in `main()`, at which point the `thread_arg` instance goes out of scope.  In order to ensure that the thread can still access that data while it's still valid, you need to either make it global data (if you only have one child thread), or allocate it dynamically on the heap.  The usual pattern for that is this:

```
// Parent thread:
thread_arg *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
...
pthread_create(..., &thread_proc, arg);

void *thread_proc(void *t_arg)
{
    thread_arg *arg = t_arg;

    // Thread code goes here
    ...
    free(arg);
    return exit_status;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Moving `open` inside the loop did the trick. For some reason I can't write anything to stdout now unless I `exit` or `return`, but debugging using files will do for now. My app was crashing (segmentation fault) sometimes, and I think that's related to your second remark. Thank you!